# Scale UIVIew upwards

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform

I have an UIView which I want to scale to double its size. I've tried these 2 commands:

```
self.bottomView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -125)
```

This one moves to the point I want but it moves the entire view so I get a gap at the bottom.(125 is my original height)

```
self.bottomView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 2)
```

This one stretches the view but it stretches both ways, up and down. I want it to only stretch in an upward Y-axis direction and not to both ways.

Which one should I continue with? Is there any way to choose which way the view should stretch? Furthermore, scaleX: y: stretches the subviews as well which isn't optimal for my cause.

Comment: In my opinion, you should calculate new position of `bottomView` and animate view with this frame. It will be as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the below API.

```
CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransform t, CGFloat sx, CGFloat sy)
```

Update only one axis: X or Y with `recognizer.scale` and keep the other one `1.0f` to achieve one direction scale.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Solution that may help you -- Just Animate your stretching operation on UIView.

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.bottomView.frame.size.height = self.bottomView.frame.size.height * 2
    }
```